# Where did my Steam gems go?

Tags: steam, steam-holiday-auction

I made about 250 gems on Dec. 15. I bid them all on a game with the miniscule possibility that I could get the game. I obviously did not. I thought that would mean that I got to keep those gems when the auction was over. But now they are all gone.

Were the gems for the auction different than the ones for the main sale? Or did I just get screwed out of all of the gems I made. Not that 250 will get me much but it would have been nice to know I had to cancel any bids I wasn't going to win.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it. You can still access the auction screen if you search for it. There are just no links on the main site to it which was the source of my confusion.

http://steamcommunity.com/auction

> Any outstanding bids have been canceled and Gems are being returned to
>   your inventory. All Gems will be returned by the end of the day.

I don't know when exactly "end of the day" is but I imagine at least by tomorrow's updated sales they should be back.

Comment: I can verify that gems are returned to user inventories.

Comment: Yea I checked mine this morning and forgot to update.